# Put horizontal arrow under text (no math)

Tags: arrows

How to add a long arrow under some words but with keeping the same text-size and (optional but really needed) adapt the line height?

The code have to be someting like:

```
Lorem \arrowed{ipsum dolor} sit amet et consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in,
```

And the expected rendering have to be something like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\arrowed[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\\[-2pt]\rightarrowfill\end{tabular}}
\newcommand\arrowedb[1]{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\\[-6pt]\rightarrowfill\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
Lorem \arrowed{ipsum dolor} sit amet et consectetur adipiscing
elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet,
adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices
diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non,
mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi,
non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa,
scelerisque vitae, consequat in,

\bigskip


Lorem \arrowedb{ipsum dolor} sit amet et consectetur adipiscing
elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet,
adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices
diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non,
mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi,
non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa,
scelerisque vitae, consequat in,
\end{document}
```

Comment: the arrow doesn't really have to be that low.  maybe zeroing out `\lineskip` would help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I moved it up `2pt` you could move it up more according to taste... (depending on real use case I'd probably move it a lot closer and `\smash` it so not opening up the lines at all...)

Comment: i think only `\smash[t]` would be safe.

Comment: @barbarabeeton but I'm feeling brave

Answer (score 1):

With a smaller arrow you can even avoid increasing the space between lines, in most cases.

*Warning: low level tricks follow.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\arrowed}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vtop{%
    \check@mathfonts
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr
      #1\vphantom{y}\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip}
      \fontsize\ssf@size\z@\selectfont\rightarrowfill\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem \arrowed{ipsum dolor} sit \arrowed{amet} et consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet,
adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam.
Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi.
Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi,
non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa,
scelerisque vitae, consequat in,

\end{document}
```

[image]

Detail in high resolution

[image]